# stm32f1xx how to use DMA to write to TIMx CCR

Tags: pwm, stm32, dma, ws2812b

I am trying to control WS2812b digital LEDs with stm32f103. I have a buffer of color values for the LED strip and to transfer them I need to write the next value to the timer's CCR every time the timer updates. As the result I should see this buffer as a PWM signal on the pin of the MC. The guy, who helped me with the PCB wired LED's data pin to `PB5` of the MC. `PB5` is connected to `TIM3_CH2`. According to the manual there is no DMA request for `TIM3_CH2`.
[image]
Does this mean it is impossible to use DMA to change `TIM3` `CCR2` every time the timer updates? I know about the DMA `burst mode` which can write to any CCR of a timer, but looks like it is impossible to send a big buffer to one CCR. What am I missing?

Comment: Haven't dug into the details of this lately, but any chance you could run another TIM3 OC channel in parallel and use that as a trigger unconnected to any pin, and have DMA load both?  Are you sure the appropriate trigger to use actually is the channel specific one.

Comment: Hmm, do you mean that I can use any timer channel as an update event for the DMA?

Comment: Another channel of the *same* timer would presumably need to be updated at the same time so a "fake" output on that (unrouted to any pin) might work as a substitute timing source

Comment: I thought  TIM3 was more general purpose.  http://www.micromouseonline.com/2016/02/04/tim3-output-compare-interrupt-on-the-stm32-family/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stm32 which timer and DMA channel should I use?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470616/stm32-which-timer-and-dma-channel-should-i-use)

Comment: This is my question too) Thanks, the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I just needed to use TIM_CHANNEL_UPDATE as update source for the DMA and set TIM3 CCR2 as an output. It just works. I used HAL library and I had to create my own `HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_DMA` and `HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop_DMA` functions.

Here is the code, it contains hardcoded values for `CCR2` and `TIM_DMA_ID_UPDATE` channel

````
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_DMA_HACK(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim, uint32_t Channel, uint32_t *pData, uint16_t Length)
{
    /* Set the DMA Period elapsed callback */
    htim->hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_UPDATE]->XferCpltCallback = TIM_DMADelayPulseCplt;

    /* Set the DMA error callback */
    htim->hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_UPDATE]->XferErrorCallback = TIM_DMAError;

    /* Enable the DMA channel */
    HAL_DMA_Start_IT(htim->hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_UPDATE], (uint32_t)pData, (uint32_t)&htim->Instance->CCR2, Length);

    /* Enable the TIM Capture/Compare 1 DMA request */
    __HAL_TIM_ENABLE_DMA(htim, TIM_DMA_UPDATE);

    /* Enable the Capture compare channel */
    TIM_CCxChannelCmd(htim->Instance, Channel, TIM_CCx_ENABLE);

    if (IS_TIM_BREAK_INSTANCE(htim->Instance) != RESET)
    {
        /* Enable the main output */
        __HAL_TIM_MOE_ENABLE(htim);
    }

    /* Enable the Peripheral */
    __HAL_TIM_ENABLE(htim);

    /* Return function status */
    return HAL_OK;
}

HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop_DMA_HACK(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim, uint32_t Channel)
{
    __HAL_TIM_DISABLE_DMA(htim, TIM_DMA_UPDATE);
    /* Disable the Capture compare channel */
    TIM_CCxChannelCmd(htim->Instance, Channel, TIM_CCx_DISABLE);

    if (IS_TIM_BREAK_INSTANCE(htim->Instance) != RESET)
    {
        /* Disable the Main Ouput */
        __HAL_TIM_MOE_DISABLE(htim);
    }

    /* Disable the Peripheral */
    __HAL_TIM_DISABLE(htim);

    /* Change the htim state */
    htim->State = HAL_TIM_STATE_READY;

    /* Return function status */
    return HAL_OK;
}
```
````